# Prove that $P(X\geq 2\alpha\beta) \leq (2/e)^{\alpha}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let X have a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I'm not so sure if my idea is correct, but I what I want to do is take the integral of the Gamma distribution via integration by parts and from $2\alpha\beta$ to infinity.  I think that's it, right?

However, I don't think this is the right answer.  My instructor somehow did this by deriving Chebyshev's inequality and applying it to the definition of a moment generating function.  How did he do that?

Comment: Is $X$ gamma distributed? If so, you should explicitly specify that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you instructor is using a Chernoff bound, with lots of optimisation. The bound itself is justified below:

$$ P(X \ge a) \overset{(i)}{=} P(e^{tX} \ge e^{ta}) \overset{(ii)}{\le} \inf_{t >0} \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]}{e^ta}$$

Where $(i)$ holds for positive $t$ as the exponent is monotonically increasing, and $(ii)$ is the Markov bound, optimised over all legitimate choices of $t$. Note that this holds for every distribution that admits a generating function in the reals.

Now, in your case,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-(\beta - t)x} dx\\
&= \left(\frac{\beta}{\beta - t}\right)^\alpha
\end{align}

For $t < \beta$.

Using the Chernoff bound,

$$P(X \ge 2\alpha\beta) \le \min_{t \in (0,\beta)} e^{-2\alpha\beta t} \left(\frac{\beta}{\beta - t}\right)^\alpha$$

Run the optimisation to get $t = \beta - \frac{1}{2\beta}$ which is in the acceptable range. This leads to

\begin{align}
P(X \ge 2\alpha\beta) &\le (2 \beta^2)^\alpha\exp( -2\alpha(\beta^2 - 1/2) )\\ \text{$ $} \\
&\le \max_{\beta >0} (2 \beta^2)^\alpha\exp( -2\alpha(\beta^2 - 1/2) )
\end{align}

Note that the inequality above is not standard, in that you wouldn't always use it, but it's completely valid. The RHS here is optimised at $\beta = 1$, which yields the expression:

$$P(X \ge 2\alpha\beta) \le 2^\alpha e^{-\alpha}$$

QED.